# Was Re:Creators originally planned to feature fictional works that actually exist in the real world?

Tags: re-creators

The basic premise of the anime *Re:Creators* is that when someone writes a book or scriptwrites a video game or something, they create an actual world where the events of the book/game/etc actually happen. Then, at the beginning of the show, some of the characters from those created worlds get transported into the "show world" (the world in which the main character [Souta] lives and in which the created worlds are works of fiction) by a Plot Device (the princess).

All of the created worlds are works of fiction that exist in the show world, but do not exist in the "real world" (the world in which you and I live), like *Avalken of Reminiscence* and *Vogelchevalier* and *Magical Slayer Mamika*.

I have noticed talk of a rumor (see e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/689wj7/spoilers_recreators_episode_4_discussion/dgwz9uj/)) that the created worlds were originally planned to be works of fiction that *do* exist in the real world, but that this plan fell through for one reason or another.

What is the source of this rumor, and how veracious is it? It sounds very *truthy*, almost to the point that I have to wonder if the source is some random guy who thought it would be cool if it actually played out that way and so originated the rumor.

Comment: Reading [the unofficial character introduction (Japanese)](http://www.loglogloglog.com/entry/recreators-character), I would say the resemblance is unavoidable, but until there's official source/interview, it might be just another parody/"respect"...

Comment: @AkiTanaka Yeah, I agree that many of the _Re:Creators_ characters have a resemblance to characters from things like _Fate_, etc. However, that isn't quite the question I'm asking: what I'm interested to know is whether _Re:Creators_ ever actually planned to use (for example) Saber herself in the show, or if the plan was always just to use a character who was an "expy" of Saber.

Answer (score 2):

As cool as it sounds, I find it highly improbable. Someone might have gotten the idea at the start of the production, but simple thought about it makes it extremely difficult to pull off.

The major hurdle is licensing. Getting licenses to all the shows and characters would be massive undertaking and would take massive amounts of time, effort and money.

Next is getting authors of other works agree to have someone else write official story with their own characters. I'm sure most authors would not be fine having their own characters being written by someone else.

There is also a problem of fitting the characters into the story. Many popular characters have clearly defined personality and fitting that personality into the story might not be easy. And while many characters are clearly influenced or based on other fictional characters, there are none who would fit into the story exactly.

Another thing is fan perception. If characters from existing stories would be used, it would change canon as seen by fans. And it is not something authors of the originals might want. And it might take some twisting of the character's personalities to fit them into the story, resulting in outrage of fans at clearly out-of-character depiction of their favorites.

So no, I don't think this was ever a worthy idea during production of Re:Creators.